# Neural networks do not work well in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to build a neural network with two inputs and one output in pytorch.
However, I get an error and cannot get it to work.

python code is below.

```
import torch
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.linear0 = nn.Linear(2, 256)
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(256, 128)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(128, 64)
        self.linear3 = nn.Linear(64, 32)
        self.linear4 = nn.Linear(32, 16)
        self.linear5 = nn.Linear(16, 8)
        self.linear6 = nn.Linear(8, 4)
        # self.linear7 = nn.Linear(4, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.linear0(x)
        x = torch.sigmoid(x)
        x = self.linear1(x)
        x = torch.sigmoid(x)
        x = self.linear2(x)
        x = torch.sigmoid(x)
        x = self.linear3(x)
        x = torch.sigmoid(x)
        x = self.linear4(x)
        x = torch.sigmoid(x)
        x = self.linear5(x)
        x = torch.sigmoid(x)
        x = self.linear6(x)
        # x = torch.sigmoid(x)
        # x = self.linear7
        return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)
net = Model()

x = torch.tensor(a[0].values)
y = torch.tensor(a[1].values)

def train(model, optimizer, E, iteration, x, y):
    losses = []
    for i in range(iteration):
        optimizer.zero_grad()                   # 勾配情報を0に初期化
        y_pred = model(x)                       # 予測
        loss = E(y_pred.reshape(y.shape), y)    # 損失を計算(shapeを揃える)
        loss.backward()                         # 勾配の計算
        optimizer.step()                        # 勾配の更新
        losses.append(loss.item())              # 損失値の蓄積
        print('epoch=', i+1, 'loss=', loss)
    return model, losses

optimizer = optim.RMSprop(net.parameters(), lr=0.01)                # 最適化にRMSpropを設定
E = nn.MSELoss()   

net, losses = train(model=net, optimizer=optimizer, E=E, iteration=5000, x=x, y=y)
y_pred = test(net, X_test)
```

input data is 2Dimention.
like this ↓

[image]

output data is 1Dimention.

### The error is as follows.

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in linear(input, weight, bias)
1846     if has_torch_function_variadic(input, weight, bias):
1847         return handle_torch_function(linear, (input, weight, bias), input, weight, bias=bias)
-> 1848     return torch._C._nn.linear(input, weight, bias)
1849
1850

### RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (1x100 and 2x256)

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an error at the first layer of your neural network because there is a dimension mismatch. The weights are shape (2,256), so it expects an input of shape (N,2).

It looks like you provide 100 training examples, so N=100, but your input is shape (100,1) instead of (100,2). In your code, it looks like `a` is (100,2), but `x = a[0]` is (100,1).